# Can I use a video file as video source for WebRTC native code?

Tags: c++, webrtc, native, video-capture

I have downloaded latest webrtc native code and tested the peerconnection example. In this example video can only come from devices configured on the system (it looks for devices in /dev/videoX).

I am wondering if it is possible to get the video from a video file at my local machine and pass its frames to VideoFrame in WebRTC so peerA, who is the peerconnection_client of the example. Then this video would be passed to peerB, who is a web client on browser.

Basically: **My video source should be a video file**.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept to get away from Google's reference implementation, the [streamer](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel/tree/master/examples/streamer) example of [libdatachannel](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel) shows how to stream a video file to a browser.